# VK api отправка документа (gif) на стену группы

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, api, вконтакте

Нужна помощь, есть скрипт отправки фото на стену группы, как сделать отправку документа?

```
if (isset($url))
{
    $upload = json_decode(curl($url, ['file' => new CURLFile($image)]));



    if (isset($upload->server))
    {
        $save = vk('docs.save', [
            'group_id' => $group_id,
            'server' => $upload->server,
            'access_token' => $access_token,
            'hash' => $upload->hash,
            'file' => $upload->file,
            'v' => '5.85'
        ])->response->upload_url; // Обращаемся сразу к <response[0]>

        if (isset($save))
        {
            $post = vk('wall.post', [
                'owner_id' => '-'.$group_id,
                'access_token' => $access_token,
                'from_group' => 1,
                'message' => $message,
                'attachments' => 'file'.$save->owner_id.'_'.$save->id,
                'v' => '5.85'
            ]);

            print_r($post);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас верный код, что не так? Вы используете верное API https://vk.com/dev/docs.getWallUploadServer

Comment: я не пойму как дальше отправить документ в Вк и опубликовать на стене. Документацию я видел но не особо понял что и как.

Comment: https://vk.com/dev/upload_files?f=10.%2B%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%2B%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2