# Загрузка gif на стену группы

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

есть код который публикует фото на стене, как его переделать под публикацию документа?

```
$post = vk('wall.post', [
                'owner_id' => '-'.$group_id,
                'access_token' => $access_token,
                'from_group' => 1,
                'message' => $message,
                'attachments' => 'photo'.$save->owner_id.'_'.$save->id,
                'v' => '5.85'
            ]);
```

Документ я загрузил в группу а вот отправить на стену не могу..
Пробовал менять photo на doc согласно документации но документ на стене так и не появился.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [VK api отправка документа (gif) на стену группы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/915793/vk-api-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-gif-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%83-%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bf%d1%8b)

Comment: Я многое из того вопроса решил, осталось дело за малым